# Should Vuex Stores use snake_case or camelCase for their names?

Tags: vuex

As the stores are files, I’m inclined to make them `snake_case.js` so they’d become `snake_case` in Vue.

However, snake case seems not to be used much in Vue, so should instead the files be `camelCase.js` so they can be refered to as `camelCase`.

I appreciate that Stack Overflow is not really for opinions, so I am seeking a guide or reference that notes the best way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [official Vue.js style guide,](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Prop-name-casing-strongly-recommended) they say

> "Within JavaScript, camelCase is more natural. Within HTML, kebab-case
> is."

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it seems much more elegant when it comes to listing and reading them inside the code using camelCase. In my organization we always use camel in the case of stores as follows:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import filtersStore from './modules/filters'
import langStore from './modules/lang'
import modulesStore from './modules/modules'
import utilStore from './modules/util'
import productsStore from './modules/products'
import catalogueStore from './modules/catalogue'
import reportsStore from './modules/reports'
import featuresStore from './modules/features'
import feedDataStore from './modules/feedData'
```

Anyway, I understand that both forms are considered good practice.

**_ EDITED _**

All the above is in /store/index.js, which is exported with:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  mutations,
  modules: {
    filtersStore,
    langStore,
    modulesStore,
    utilStore,
    productsStore,
    catalogueStore,
    reportsStore,
    featuresStore,
    feedDataStore
  }
})
```

and globally imported un main vue's app.js like:

```
import store from './store'
```

Comment: Interesting that you append `Store` to them – how do you use them in your project? We only use them with a `dispatch`, so we consider the ‘store’ part is implied.

Comment: Hey @ThomasEdwards! We use them like `...mapGetters({
      feedData: 'feedDataStore/getFeedData'
    })`.  In this way we organize a little the "stores" by type/context. 
I will edit my answer to explain it a little better.